# cut down form spam submission

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

I have a form on my website which provides a way of contact between my advertisers and their potential customers, unfortunately, there is a lot of spam being sent to my advertisers which I need to try to stop. As most of the spam contains lots of text content I would like to have it set that if it contains 140 words or more the message is sent to me to verify it's not spam.

This form is automatically sent to my advertisers, so I need a way of overriding sending it based on the number of words in the message section.

I'm not sure how to implement this into the smarty contact.php file below.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$go = TRUE;
//they have submitted the form//
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['fromemail']) && !empty($_POST['message']) && $go == TRUE) {
//data has been filled
$name = Filter::no_html($_POST['name']);
$from = Filter::no_html($_POST['fromemail']);
$start_dt = Filter::no_html($_POST['start_dt']);
$end_dt = Filter::no_html($_POST['end_dt']);
$comments = Filter::no_html($_POST['message']);
$validate - > isEmpty($name, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER.
" ".LANG_YOUR_NAME);
$validate - > isEmpty($from, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER.
" ".LANG_YOUR_EMAIL);
$validate - > isSingleEmail($from, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER_EMAIL);
$validate - > isEmpty($comments, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER.
" ".LANG_YOUR_MESSAGE);
$modules - > call_hook('contact_owner_submit', ''); // Call any module functions
$id = (int) @$_POST['ownerid'];
$vehicle = (int) @$_POST['listingid'];

if ($validate - > isError()) {
$errors = $validate - > getErrorList();

$errorText = "<b>The operation could not be performed because one or more error(s) occurred.</b> <p> Please resubmit the form after making the following changes:</p>";
$errorText. = "<ol>";
foreach($errors as $e) {
$errorText. = "<li>".$e['msg'].
                "</li>";
}
$errorText. = "</ol>";
$class_tpl - > assign('msg', $errorText);

//assign the vars back
foreach($_POST as $item => $k) //@TODO remove if these being assigned twice
{
$class_tpl - > assign(Filter::special_chars($item), Filter::special_chars($k));
}

$class_tpl - > assign('title', $title);
$class_tpl - > assign('name', Filter::special_chars($_POST['name']));
$class_tpl - > assign('fromemail', Filter::special_chars($_POST['fromemail']));
$class_tpl - > assign('message', Filter::special_chars($_POST['message']));
$class_tpl - > assign('start_dt', Filter::special_chars($_POST['start_dt']));
$class_tpl - > assign('end_dt', Filter::special_chars($_POST['end_dt']));
$class_tpl - > assign('lid', Filter::special_chars($_POST['listingid']));
$class_tpl - > assign('owner', Filter::special_chars($_POST['ownerid']));
$class_tpl - > assign('body', 'contact/contactowner.tpl');
} else {
//update the replied count
$sSQL = "UPDATE ".PREFIX.
"listings SET repliedcount=repliedcount+1 WHERE id=".Filter::mysql_quote($vehicle);
$db - > query($sSQL);

//now get the user information
$sSQL = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email,username FROM ".PREFIX.
"users WHERE id=".Filter::mysql_quote($id);
$result = $db - > query($sSQL);
$rs = $result - > fetch();
$to_first_name = $rs['firstname'];
$to_last_name = $rs['lastname'];
$to = $rs['email'];
$to_username = $rs['username'];

//now the vehicle information
$sSQL = "SELECT id,title FROM ".PREFIX.
"listings WHERE id=".Filter::mysql_quote($vehicle);
$result = $db - > query($sSQL);
$rs = $result - > fetch();
$vehicle = $rs['id'];
$ltitle = $rs['title'];
$sitetitle = $title;

$vars['listing_url'] = $modules - > call_hook('listing_url', $rs);
if ($vars['listing_url'] == '') {
$vars['listing_url'] = URL.
"/viewlisting.php?view=".$vehicle;
}

$vars['name'] = $name;
$vars['email'] = $to;
$vars['fromemail'] = $from;
$vars['name'] = $name;
$vars['comments'] = $comments;
$vars['start_dt'] = $start_dt;
$vars['end_dt'] = $end_dt;
$vars['sitetitle'] = $sitetitle;
$vars['to_first_name'] = $to_first_name;
$vars['to_last_name'] = $to_last_name;
$vars['to_username'] = $to_username;
$content = "contactowner.tpl";
$msg = $Mailer - > sendMail($to, $content, $vars);

if ($msg == TRUE) {
$class_tpl - > assign('pPageContent', LANG_CONTACT_SUCCESS_BODY);
$class_tpl - > assign('body', 'content.tpl');
} else {
$class_tpl - > assign('title', LANG_ERROR);
$class_tpl - > assign('pPageContent', $msg);
$class_tpl - > assign('body', 'content.tpl');
}
$class_tpl - > display('layout.tpl');
die();

}
} else {
//show the form again
$class_tpl - > assign('title', $title);
$class_tpl - > assign('name', Filter::special_chars($_POST['name']));
$class_tpl - > assign('fromemail', Filter::special_chars($_POST['fromemail']));
$class_tpl - > assign('message', Filter::special_chars($_POST['message']));
$class_tpl - > assign('start_dt', Filter::special_chars($_POST['start_dt']));
$class_tpl - > assign('end_dt', Filter::special_chars($_POST['end_dt']));
$class_tpl - > assign('lid', (int) $_POST['listingid']);
$class_tpl - > assign('owner', (int) $_POST['ownerid']);
$class_tpl - > assign('body', 'contact/contactowner.tpl');
}
} else {
$class_tpl - > assign('title', $title);
$class_tpl - > assign('name', Filter::special_chars($_REQUEST['name']));
$class_tpl - > assign('fromemail', Filter::special_chars($_REQUEST['fromemail']));
$class_tpl - > assign('message', Filter::special_chars($_REQUEST['message']));
$class_tpl - > assign('start_dt', Filter::special_chars($_REQUEST['start_dt']));
$class_tpl - > assign('end_dt', Filter::special_chars($_REQUEST['end_dt']));
$class_tpl - > assign('lid', (int) $_REQUEST['listingid']);
$class_tpl - > assign('owner', (int) $_REQUEST['ownerid']);
$class_tpl - > assign('body', 'contact/contactowner.tpl');
}
$class_tpl - > display('layout.tpl');
```

Comment: Maybe count the words in message by splitting on space?

Comment: It can even be by counting the characters not words, I just need a way of checking the message but I'm not sure how or where to place the checking statement in the contact.php file.